# What is the shortest way to temporarily bypass function in zsh?

Tags: shell, zsh

In my .zshrc I define a wrapper function for `cd` as below.

```
function cd(){
  builtin cd "$@" && ls -AFG
}
```

(print content of directory when changed directory)

Sometimes I want to use original `cd` (change directory without print content).
Though `builtin cd` or `command cd` should works, but is there a shorter way to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not to use different name for your function? `cdd` or `ccd` for example. This way you don't need to mask shell's `cd` command

Answer (score 3):

You can unset the function in `zsh` using the
`unfunction` built-in command.

Example:

`$ unfunction cd`

Comment: `unset -f` works too. I do not know if there is a difference beyond `unset` being available in other shells.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to wrap the `cd` builtin command with a function called `cd`,
and you occasionally want to change directory without calling the function,
but typing `builtin cd` interactively is too tedious for you,
define a function that does `builtin cd` and nothing else. 
For example,

```
function pcd(){
  builtin cd "$@"
}
```

will give you "plain" `cd` command that you can access by typing `pcd`.